# Cox proportional hazards with multiclass dependent variable

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, multi-class, proportional-hazards

Is it possible to perform a multiclass Cox proportional hazards model?
I'm interested in finding the probability of self cure on consumer loans, or just study how self-curing clients behave so as to identify future customers that behave the same way. My dependent variable of interest has 3 classes:
-not cured (0)
-cured after being contacted (1)
-self cured (2)

I was thinking maybe two regressions have to be run in this case (similarly as in the multinomial logit), one where it's 0 vs 1, and another where it is 0 vs 2, maybe another 1 vs 2?

I tried looking for this but I didn't find anything, so I'm wondering if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a fairly straightforward "competing risks" analysis. If "cured" is your event, then you simply code the event differently depending on whether it was a "self-cure" or "cure-after-being-contacted". In general, instead of a coding {0,1} for {censored, event} you code {0,1,2,...} for {censored, eventType1, eventType2, ...}. That's handled pretty simply in the R `survival` package, for example. See Section 2.3 of the main [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) of that package.

You don't want to do this analysis separately on different types of events. As the vignette says (Section 2.3.2):

> A common mistake with competing risks is to use the Kaplan-Meier separately on each event type while treating other event types as censored.

See the vignette for further details. If you want more background, do a search on "competing risks" in survival analysis.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be what I was looking for, I didn't know such a thing existed. I wonder though, isn't Multi-state data in section 2.4 more ideal to my model?

Comment: Also, do you know if these competing risks models account for recurrent events as well? Because that's the shape of my data (many stages for the same unit)

Comment: @amestrian multi-state models with arbitrary transition patterns and competing risks are possible to model this way. See the [multi-state vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) for the [`survival` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=survival). Of course it gets more complicated the more transitions that you allow, and data formatting might get dicey. I don't have any substantive experience with such models, but now you know the buzz-words for which to search.